# My current problem is that I want to separate a string into single words and punctuation marks but don't know how

Tags: c#, console-application

(SearchTool)
Currently I have a very long string which can contain several words including punctuation marks or brackets. However, my problem now is that when I type a search term like "apple" I filter my text string by spaces, so I only get the single characters. But because it can happen that the text says ""apple,""" would be the split word ""apple,"" now I still have to separate the com from it somehow is there a possibility to realize it with all special characters?

```
 string[] splittedTxt = text.Split(' ');

        if (decisionForWholeWords == true && decisionForSpelling == false)
        {
            foreach (var item in splittedTxt)
            {

                if (wordToFind.ToLower() == item.ToLower())
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    var cursorPositionTop = Console.CursorTop;
                    var cursorPositionLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                    wordFound = true;
                    foundWordPositions.Add(new CursorPosition(cursorPositionTop, cursorPositionLeft));
                }
                Console.Write(item);
                if (wordFound) // reset color
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

                    wordFound = false;
                }
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern `\w+`

Matches exactly `apple` from `""apple,""`

A useful regex tester and reference: http://regexstorm.net/reference

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you build an array with the chars you want to split, something like this:

```
string mystring = "This is some, bla bla. ble, hey guys";
char[] delimiters = { ',', '.' }; //you can add your delimiters in this array
string[] result = myString.Split(delimiters);
```

The output will be:

```
"This is some"
" bla bla"
" ble"
" hey guys"
```

Comment: But so I lose the punctuation marks if I want to print the text colored on the console again.